# Shaving huge tree's roots without damaging tree

Tags: trees, roots

A huge Black Walnut Tree 3 feet from my pool has lifted the ground and fiberglass stairs.  Can I shave some root off so I can reset the stairs without risking the tree?

Comment: You mean 2% of the roots? Sure.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, for a meaningful answer, you may need to post a picture.  And the tree will keep growing so this wouldn't be a long term solution.  In fact, it could actually already be damaging your pool.